# Apache use php as input filter

Tags: apache

I have an apache2 vhost that is a reverse proxy to another site. It has an output and input filter defined, yet the input script doesnt run - when trying to put the stdin into a file, it is created but it is empty. I tried to script with 
`echo 'hello world' | php i.php` and it works fine. Tried it with a bash script and it doesnt work for apache as well - but again works for echo.

Filter definitions:

```
ExtFilterDefine ifr mode=input cmd="/usr/bin/php /mnt/hdd0/html/sap/filters/i.php"
ExtFilterDefine ofr mode=output cmd="/usr/bin/php /mnt/hdd0/html/sap/filters/o.php"

SetInputFilter ifr
SetOutputFilter ofr
```

i.php

```
$req = file_get_contents("php://stdin");

file_put_contents("/mnt/hdd0/html/sap/filters/request.txt", $req);
file_put_contents("php://stdout", $req);
```

It seems that apache is not putting anything into stdin - or am I wrong somewhere?